# How to create a folder/file on iPhone device Library?

Tags: iphone, ios

I like to access the device Library folder (not app's document directory). Actually i am trying to create one file in Device Library folder and want to access this file from another app. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, apps in the iOS are sandboxed and can only write in there own environment. Also there is no library directory.

Answer (score 1):

Finally now it is possible with app extension, but after 3 years :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keychain if you really want data transfer between applications.